# Python - ¿Cómo puedo hacer una lista de listas a partir de una lista?

Tags: python, lista

Teniendo la siguiente lista:

```
lista=["carla", 82, 24, "andres", 873, 98]
```

Necesito crear una lista de listas en donde cada lista dentro de esta nueva lista tenga 3 elementos de la lista original, donde debe quedar algo así:

```
lista2=[["carla", 82, 84], ["andres", 873, 98]]
```

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida añade el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: `listaDef = [lista[:3], lista[3:]]`

Comment: Es difícil de entender: `list(zip(*[iter(lista)]*3))`. En las recetas del módulo `itertools` aparece.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ["Carla",22,23,"Andres",24,25, "Julia",52,53]
r = []
i = 0
while i < len(l):
    r.append([l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2]])
    i=i+3 
print(r)

[['Carla', 22, 23], ['Andres', 24, 25], ['Julia', 52, 53]]
```

Mejor, gracias a @DanteS ;)

```
l = ["Carla",22,23,"Andres",24,25, "Julia",52,53]
lista2 = [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]
print(lista2)
[['Carla', 22, 23], ['Andres', 24, 25], ['Julia', 52, 53]]
```

Comment: Puedes reemplazar el `while` por un `for`y eliminar dos instrucciones: `r = []
for i in range(0, len(l), 3):
    r.append([l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2]])`

Comment: @CandidMoe podrías mejorarlo aun más asi: `r.append(l[i:i+3])` :-)

Comment: E incluso puedes usar una comprension de listas así `lista2 = [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]`

Comment: La propuesta de @DanteS. es ciertamente la mejor , pero es mas entendible un bonito `for` aparte (? jajaja

Answer (score 0):

Puedes asignar cada lista a una variable y luego declaras otra variable que usarás con el método append.
**Nota: por lo que veo Carla y Andres son cadenas de string por ello en mi respuesta los coloco entre comillas..**

```
lista=["carla",82,24,"andres",873,98]
listaOne= lista[0:3]
listaTwo= lista[3:6]
listaDef = []
listaDef.append(listaOne)
listaDef.append(listaTwo)
print(listaDef)
```

Comment: Revisa tu respuesta. La ejecución de este código arroja `[['carla', 82], ['andres', 873]]`

Comment: Gracias @CandidMoe, estaré editando la respuesta.